# How to declare and set a value in SQL?

Tags: sql, variables

I am trying to simply declare and set variables in SQL.
I am still learning and using and online platform such as this one https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_no_distinct

I am simply doing this:

```
DECLARE @Var1 INT;
SET @Var1 = 1;
```

And I already have an error message for the first line

```
Error: near line 1: near "DECLARE": syntax error Error: near line 17: near "SET": syntax error
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you

Comment: Which Database Management System are you using? The syntax can differ between systems.

Comment: Should work in SQL Server at least.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your statement, please tag which specific database you are using and provide a DB<>Fiddle demonstrating your error.

Comment: As the error is on line 17 you've left out a good portion of the code.

Comment: That site is not using SQL Server. You'll need to find a good WebSQL reference instead.

Comment: Looks like it uses sqllite. If you want to try SQL Server syntax in a browser you can use https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: There is nothing from my side on line 17. Although I am using a platform (the one I put as a link) to learn and do not work with my own DB. That might be the reason then. In that case where would you recommend and easy online database access to learn SQL properly since I don't have my own system?